# Flutter : Return data object from new screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to return data as object from second screen. In example they only send as string, what if I wanna return data as json object. I have try:
I use [Json serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)

**class**

```
class LeaveFilterType {
   String shortName;
   String fullName;
   LeaveFilterType({this.shortName, this.fullName});
   factory LeaveFilterType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LeaveFilterTypeFromJson(json);
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LeaveFilterTypeToJson(this);
}
```

**screen 1**

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () async{
    var result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => FilterView(leaveRequestTypeList: requestTypeList, requestState: RequestState.Supervisor)));
       var finalResult = jsonDecode(result);
       print("result $finalResult");
       FilterLeave filterLeave = FilterLeave.fromJson(finalResult);
       print("result ${filterLeave.toJson()}");
    },
    icon: Image.asset(ImagePath.icFilter, width: AppDimen.value18, color: AppColor.grey,),
)
```

**screen 2**

```
IconButton(
    splashColor: AppColor.white,
    icon: Icon(Icons.check),
    color: AppColor.white,
    onPressed: () async {
        print(leaveRequest.toJson());
        var filterLeave = FilterLeave(type: leaveRequest, startDate: startDateController.text, endDate :endDateController.text);
         Navigator.of(context).pop("${leaveRequest}");
        }
    ),
 )
```

Always got error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
 Instance of 'LeaveFilterType'
```

Comment: *"In example they only send as string, what if I wanna return data as json object."* - so you mean `pop(leaveRequest)`? why do you want to `pop` the `String`?

Comment: I have used ${.....} in side double quote

Comment: and what is double quote? its a `String` isnt it? so you want to return a `String` or not?

Comment: I want to return leaveRequest object

Comment: see my first comment above then

Comment: It works. Thanks man. The problem is it actually return object, but I was very confused.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can just return any object from `Navigator.pop(context, result)`

In a project of mine I did the following with a dialog:

```
DialogResponseObject returnValue = await showDialog<DialogResponseObject>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
      CustomDialog(),
);
```

In the dialog:

```
Navigator.pop<DialogResponse>(context,DialogResponseObject(dialogAnswer));
```

Should work the same for your case.
You can actually type in Navigator.push from the first screen and there should be no need to serialize.

```
   FilterLeave result = await Navigator.push<FilterLeave>(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => FilterView(leaveRequestTypeList: requestTypeList, requestState: RequestState.Supervisor)));


FilterLeave filterLeave = FilterLeave(type: leaveRequest, startDate: startDateController.text, endDate :endDateController.text);
     Navigator.of(context).pop<FilterLeave>(leaveRequest);
```